# How to call a parametrized getter as a mapper in a java 8 stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

## Use Case

I currently have this pattern in many adapters:

```
entries.stream()
        .filter(Entry.class::isInstance)
        .map(Entry.class::cast)
        .map(Entry::getFooBar)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where entries is a `List` of objects that implement a particular interface. Unfortunately, the interface - which is a part of a 3rd party library - does not define the common getters. To create a list of the objects I want, I need to search for them, cast them, and call the appropriate getter method.

I was going to refactor it into a helper class as such:

```
public static <T, O> List<O> entriesToBeans(List<T> entries, 
        Class<T> entryClass, Supplier<O> supplier) {
    return entries.stream()
            .filter(entryClass::isInstance)
            .map(entryClass::cast)
            .map(supplier)                  // <- This line is invalid
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I would then call this method to do the conversion:

```
Helper.entriesToBeans(entries, 
                      Entry_7Bean.class, 
                      Entry_7Bean::getFooBar);
```

Unfortunately, I can't pass the getter into the refactored function and have the map call it because the `map` is expecting a function.

### Question

- How can the getter be called in the refactored version?

Comment: Why are you performing `.filter(entryClass::isInstance).map(entryClass::cast)` when the source is a `List<T>` and `entryClass` is a `Class<T> `, in other words, the source is already guaranteed to contain appropriately typed items only?

Comment: @Holger it would probably make more sense with a `List<? super T>`

Comment: @assylias: simply `List<?>` as there is no relationship to `<T>` anyway.

Comment: @Holger yup - you're right again! ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A method like:

```
class T {
  public O get() { return new O(); }
}
```

will map to a `Function<T, O>`.

So you can simply need to change your method signature to:

```
public static <T, O> List<O> entriesToBeans(List<T> entries,
        Class<T> entryClass, Function<T, O> converter) {
```

**Update**: the reason for the cast, I suspect, is that your original list may contain elements that are not Ts. So you could also change the signature to:

```
public static <T, O> List<O> entriesToBeans(List<?> entries,
        Class<T> entryClass, Function<T, O> converter) {
```

You can then pass a `List<Object>`, for example, and only keep the Ts in the list, cast and convert.

---

For reference, here is a working example (prints `John, Fred`):

```
static class Person {
  private final String name;
  Person(String name) { this.name = name; }
  String name() { return name; }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<String> result = entriesToBeans(Arrays.asList(new Person("John"), new Person("Fred")),
                                       Person.class, Person::name);
  System.out.println("result = " + result);
}

public static <T, O> List<O> entriesToBeans(List<?> entries,
        Class<T> entryClass, Function<T, O> converter) {
  return entries.stream()
          .filter(entryClass::isInstance)
          .map(entryClass::cast)
          .map(converter)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Java complains when I try this: `Helper.entriesToBeans(entries, Entry_7Bean.class, Entry_7Bean::getFooBar);`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it's still producing errors on the calling side. `The type Entry_7Bean does not define getFooBar(T) that is applicable`. For some reason, it sees the method reference as an object.

Comment: Oh I found out that the getter has to be static... which makes sense. Would it be possible to somehow have the map call the instance method using the supplier/converter?

Comment: @Pete ignore my previous comment. You should not need to make it static. See full example in my edited answer.

Comment: I don't get it. Is the filter and first map necessary? You have a `List<T>` and a mapper from T to O. Can't you simply do `stream().map(converter).collect(...)` ?

Comment: @AlexisC. This is just a simplified use case. I'm working with a 3rd party library that returns a list of mixed objects. Unfortunately, the interface doesn't define *any* common methods that I want to get. Sad thing is that all classes that implement that interface have a method called `getSection()` - which is what I want to retrieve.

Comment: @Pete Ah I see. Because the generics bounds in your question were a non-sense for those operations.

Comment: @assylias Found the problem that was causing the error. You were absolutely correct that I had to use `? super T`. I'll update the question to improve the context so people in the future will  understand what's going on. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Pete as commented by Holger, `List<?>` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass a `Function<T, O>` instead:

```
public static <T, O> List<O> entriesToBeans(List<T> entries, Class<T> entryClass, 
                               Function<T, O> mapper) {
    return entries.stream().filter(entryClass::isInstance)
                  .map(entryClass::cast).map(mapper)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: What’s this `::apply` thing? Why is everyone so interesting in converting a `Function` into a `Function`? Just because method references look so fancy?

Comment: @Holger Damn it. I always do this :(

Comment: Fascinatingly, you’re not the only one…